# discord.enums bug occurring when server starts

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I log in to my computer and try to run the Discord bot, a discord.enums bug appears. I will write down the phrase in question below.

```
An exception occurred. ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'discord.enums'

File "C:\Users\user\DreamPilot Flightplan bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from discord import app_commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.enums'
```

I've tried many different methods, including turning the computer off and on, downloading the latest versions of VSC and Python, and asking questions in various places, but bugs keep happening.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code where the error occurs

Comment: I don't think that is the full error message.  Please post the full error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.